# Ошибка TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType

Tags: python

Читал книгу Майкла Доусона "Программируем на Python". В 6 главе объясняется работа функций на примере игры "Крестики-нолики". Собрал всё вместе, запустил. Привожу сам код.

```
    # Крестики-нолики
# Компьютер играет в крестики-нолики против пользователя
# глобальные константы
X = "X"
O = "0"
EMPTY = " "
TIE = "Ничья"
NUM_SQUARES = 9

def display_instruct():
    """Выводит на экран инструкцию для игрока."""
    print(
        """
        Добро пожаловать на ринг грандиознейших интеллектуальных состязаний всех времен.
        Твой мозг и мой процессор сойдутся в схватке за доской игры "Крестики-нолики".

        Чтобы сделать ход, введи число от 0 до 8. Числа однозначно соответствуют полям доски - так, как показано ниже:
        0 | 1 | 2
        ---------
        3 | 4 | 5
        ---------
        6 | 7 | 8
        Приготовься к бою, жалкий белковый человечишка. Вот-вот начнётся решающее сражение.\n
        """
    )

def ask_yes_no(question):
    """Задаёт вопрос с ответом 'Да' или 'Нет'."""
    response = None
    while response not in ('y', 'n'):
        response = input(question).lower()
    return response

def ask_number(question, low, high):
    """Просит ввести число из диапазона."""
    response = None
    while response not in range(low, high):
        response = int(input(question))
    return response

def pieces():
    """Определяет принадлежность первого хода."""
    go_first = ask_yes_no("Хочешь оставить за собой первый ход? (y/n): ")
    if go_first == "y":
        print("\nНу что ж, даю тебе фору: играй крестиками.")
        human = X
        computer = O
    else:
        print("\nТвоя удаль тебя погубит... Буду начинать я.")
        computer = X
        human = O
    return computer, human

def new_board():
    """Создаёт новую игровую доску."""
    board = []
    for square in range(NUM_SQUARES):
        board.append(EMPTY)
    return board

def display_board(board):
    """Отображает игровую доску на экране."""
    print("\n\t", board[0], " | ", board[1], " | ", board[2])
    print("\t", "-------------")
    print("\t", board[3], " | ", board[4], " | ", board[5])
    print("\t", "-------------")
    print("\t", board[6], " | ", board[7], " | ", board[8], "\n")

def legal_moves(board):
    moves = []
    for place in range(NUM_SQUARES):
        if board[place] == EMPTY:
            moves.append(place)
        return moves

def winner(board):
    """Определяет победителя в игре."""
    WAYS_TO_WIN = ((0, 1, 2),
                   (3, 4, 5),
                   (6, 7, 8),
                   (0, 3, 6),
                   (1, 4, 7),
                   (2, 5, 8),
                   (0, 4, 8),
                   (2, 4, 6))
    for row in WAYS_TO_WIN:
        if board[row[0]] == board[row[1]] == board[row[2]] != EMPTY:
            winner = board[row[0]]
            return winner
        if EMPTY not in board:
            return TIE
    return None

def human_move(board):
    """Получает ход человека."""
    legal = legal_moves(board)
    move = None
    while move not in legal:
        move = ask_number("Твой ход. Выбери одной из полей (0 - 8): ", 0, NUM_SQUARES)
        if move not in legal:
            print("\nСмешной человек! Это поле уже занято. Выбери другое.\n")
    print("Ладно...")
    return move

def computer_move(board, computer, human):
    """Делает ход за компьютерного противника."""
    # Создадим рабочую копию доски, потому что функция будет менять некоторые значения в списке
    board = board[:]
    # Поля от лучшего к худшему
    BEST_MOVES = (4, 0, 2, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7)
    print("Я выберу поле номер", end = " ")
    for move in legal_moves(board):
        board[move] = computer
        # Если следующим ходом может победить компьютер, выберем этот ход
        if winner(board) == computer:
            print(move)
            return move
        elif winner(board) == human:
            print(move)
            return move
        # Выполнив проверку, отменим внесённые изменения
        board[move] = EMPTY
        # Поскольку следующим ходом ни одна сторона не может победить,
        # выберем лучшее из доступных полей
    for move in BEST_MOVES:
        if move in legal_moves(board):
            print(move)
            return move

def next_turn(turn):
    """Осуществляет переход хода."""
    if turn == X:
        return O
    else:
        return X

def congrat_winner(the_winner, computer, human):
    """Поздравляет победителя игры."""
    if the_winner != TIE:
        print("Три ", the_winner, " в ряд!\n")
    else:
        print("Ничья!\n")
    if the_winner == computer:
        print("Как я и предсказывал, победа в очередной раз осталась за мной. \n" \
              "Вот ещё один довод в пользу того, что компьютеры превосходят людей решительно во всём.")
    elif the_winner == human:
        print("О нет, этого не может быть! Неужели ты как-то сумел перехитрить меня, белковый? \n" \
              "Клянусь: я, компьютер, нк допущу этого больше никогда!")
    elif the_winner == TIE:
        print("Тебе несказанно повезло, дружок: ты сумел свести игру вничью. \n" \
              "Радуйся же сегодняшнему успеху! Завтра тебе уже не суждено его повторить.")


def main():
    display_instruct()
    computer, human = pieces()
    turn = X
    board = new_board()
    display_board(board)
    while not winner(board):
        if turn == human:
            move = human_move(board)
            board[move] = human
        else:
            move = computer_move(board, computer, human)
            board[move] = computer
        display_board(board)
        turn = next_turn(turn)
    the_winner = winner(board)
    congrat_winner(the_winner, computer, human)

# Запуск программы
main()
input("\n\nНажмите Enter, чтобы выйти.")
```

Компьютер считает, что пустое только поле под номером 0. После первого хода программа завершается этой ошибкой. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Компьютер считает, что пустое только поле под номером 0.

В функции `legal_moves()` у вас `return moves` стоит в цикле и возвращается после первой итерации, нужно убрать лишний отступ

Comment: Помогло, большое спасибо.

Comment: Если вместе со следующим комментарием всё наладилось, то можно отметить вопрос как решённый, пожалуй

Answer (score 0):

Возникла новая проблема. Всё работает отлично, за исключением того, что компьютер порой даёт человеку выиграть, хотя в коде написано, что если следующим ходом может выиграть человек, надо походить на это поле.

```
def computer_move(board, computer, human):
    """Делает ход за компьютерного противника."""
    # Создадим рабочую копию доски, потому что функция будет менять некоторые значения в списке
    board = board[:]
    # Поля от лучшего к худшему
    BEST_MOVES = (4, 0, 2, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7)
    print("Я выберу поле номер", end = " ")
    for move in legal_moves(board):
        board[move] = computer
        # Если следующим ходом может победить компьютер, выберем этот ход
        if (winner(board) == computer) or (winner(board) == human):
            print(move)
            return move
        # Выполнив проверку, отменим внесённые изменения
        board[move] = EMPTY
        # Поскольку следующим ходом ни одна сторона не может победить,
        # выберем лучшее из доступных полей
    for move in BEST_MOVES:
        if move in legal_moves(board):
            print(move)
            return move
```

Comment: Смотрите, у вас компьютер смотрит, может ли выиграть человек, если на какую-то клетку походит компьютер. Это бессмысленное условие, каждый игрок может выиграть только в свой ход. Надо сначала проверить, что компьютер выиграет, если походит в какую-то клетку, а потом проверить, что человек выиграет, если походит в эту клетку, и тогда её закрывать. 
Вообще удобнее было бы, если бы отредактировали вопрос, а не добавили свой ответ, который ответом не является, тогда можно было бы прикрепить код с правильной логикой

Comment: @Liquid, если у вас возник новый вопрос - задайте его отдельно. Поле "Ваш ответ" предназначено только для ответов.